# How to aggregate an array data in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregate

I've some problems to make an aggregation query work fine in MongoDB.

I've this json schema:

```
{
    "_id" : 11,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"],
    "pools" : [ 
        {
            "score" : 2,
            "language" : "en",
            "option" : "Have problems to close!",
            "time" : "2017-06-06"
        }, 
        {
            "score" : 1,
            "language" : "en",
            "option" : "I can't close this door!",
            "time" : "2017-06-06"
        }, 
        {
            "score" : 4,
            "language" : "en",
            "option" : "After some time, I'm able to install this door. Works fine!",
            "time" : "2017-06-06"
        }, 
        {
            "score" : 5,
            "language" : "fr",
            "option" : "Très difficile à installer, mais ça marche quand même.",
            "time" : "2017-06-06"
        }, 
        {
            "score" : 1,
            "language" : "es",
            "option" : "Perdí mucho tiempo para instalar.",
            "time" : "2017-06-06"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to filter only the registries that have language in English ("en") and score equal or greater than 3. So, I try this:

```
db.test.aggregate(
    { $match: { "pools.language": "en" }},
    { $match: {"pools.score": { $gte : 3 }}},
    { $unwind: '$pools'})
```

However, I always get results in other languages and incoherent scores.

So, how to write this correctly?

Comment: There is two correct answers on this post from Shubham and Foodtooth.  Thank you so much for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.test.aggregate([{ 
   $addFields:{
  pools:{
    $filter:{
     input:"$pools",
     as:"p",
     cond:{$and:[{$eq:["$$p.language","en"]},{$gte:["$$p.score",3]}]}
    }}
  }

}])
```

for < mongodb 3.4

```
db.test.aggregate([{ 
   $project:{
"_id" : 1,
"name":1,
"price":1,
"tags":1,
  pools:{
    $filter:{
     input:"$pools",
     as:"p",
     cond:{$and:[{$eq:["$$p.language","en"]},{$gte:["$$p.score",3]}]}
    }}
  }

}])
```

Comment: Hello Shubham, Thank your help with this query. I get the error message: : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields'" because I'm using MongoDB 3.2 and this stage isn't available, but I believe that this solution can work. I'll try to do an upgrade and give a feedback to you. Have nice day. Regards.

Comment: just use $project stage then

Comment: The upgrade has some interesting features, so I'm working on it. But, thank you for the tip. I'll back soon that I finish this process.

Comment: Hello Shubham, Congratulations, the query work fine after upgrade the MongoDB database to the version 3.6. Thank you so much for your help. Have a nice day, Regards.

Comment: Hail mongo db . Happy coding :)

Comment: Hail mongo db ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should first unwind the pools and then run the matches:

```
db.getCollection('notification_collection').aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$pools'},
    { $match: { "pools.language": "en" }},
    { $match: {"pools.score": { $gte : 3 }}}
)
```

Comment: Hello Eli,  Thank you so much for your help and time. I also try it, but I don't receive any results. Regards,

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/

> In the db.collection.aggregate method, pipeline stages appear in an array. Documents pass through the stages in sequence

So you should first unwind, and multiple matches can use `$and` operator:

```
db.test.aggregate(
  { $unwind: '$pools' },
  { $match:
    { $and: [{ "pools.language": "en" }, { "pools.score": { $gte: 3 } }]}
  }
)
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for the orientation and for your time. I already try it, but I don't receive any results. I try many ways without a positive result. If you have more ideas, please share with me. Have nice day, Regards.

Comment: Is there any error, or just empty result? This is a working example in my mongo shell, with the data you provided.

Comment: Just an empty result. I believe that the problem is my MongoDB version, I'm using the 3.2. I'll upgrade to the version 3.6 and try again. After do that, I'll share the result with you.

Comment: Hello, Congratulations foodtooth! After perform the upgrade the query work fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad it helped.